# How to create a collection of different types objects to use it with polymorphis

Tags: java, list, overloading

I have a problem with the different type of objects in a collection, in that case ArrayList, here there is an example:

```
public interface CustomObject {}
public class CustomObjectA implements CustomObjects {}
public class CustomObjectB implements CustomObjects {}
```

In the main I call myMethod:

```
ArrayList<CustomObject> list = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {
   myMethod(list.get(i));
}
```

myMethod is defined with an overloading as written below:

```
public void myMethod(CustomObjectA a) { ... }
public void myMethod(CustomObjectB b) { ... }
```

There is a compile-error. How can I solve? What's the right way to it (Collections, generics, wildcard ?)

Comment: What compile error? On which line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to work around this is the use of the visitor pattern, which allows you to attach functionality, without touching your domain objects

```
// A visitor, which can 'visit' all your types
interface CustomObjectVisitor {
    void visitA(CustomObjectA a);
    void visitB(CustomObjectB b);
}

// Make CustomObject a visitee
public interface CustomObject {
    void accept(CustomObjectVisitor visitor);
}

// Implement the classes with the accept method
public class CustomObjectA implements CustomObject {
    @Override public void accept(CustomObjectVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visitA(this);
    }
}
public class CustomObjectB implements CustomObject {
    @Override public void accept(CustomObjectVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visitB(this);
    }
}
```

Now you can make your `Main` class a visitor like this:

```
public class Main implements CustomObjectVisitor {
    public void methodThatDidntWorkBefore() {
        ArrayList<CustomObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(CustomObject obj: list) {
            obj.accept(this);
        }
    }

    @Override public void visitA(CustomObjectA a) { ... }
    @Override public void visitB(CustomObjectB b) { ... }
}
```

Check out [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) too, it's really useful once you wrap your head around it.

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
public interface CustomObject { void myMethod(); }
public class CustomObjectA implements CustomObjects {
    @Override
    public void myMethod() {...}
}
public class CustomObjectB implements CustomObjects {
    @Override
    public void myMethod() {...}
}
```

Then:

```
ArrayList<CustomObject> list = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {
   list.get(i).myMethod(); // invoke dynamic
}
```

Which will execute the method corresponding to what the object's dynamic type is.

e.g. If `get(i)` returns an object with a dynamic type of `CustomObjectA` it will execute `CustomObjectA::myMethod`.

Comment: thanks, but is there a way to separate myMethod() from the classes CustomObjectsA and CustomObjectsB and put it (the method) in another classes, that in my case is the controller (MVC)

Comment: @GuidoMuscioni You could implement the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
public class myMethodClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<CustomObject> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {
           myMethod(list.get(i));
        }
    }

    public static void myMethod(CustomObject o){
        if(o instanceof CustomObjectA) myMethod((CustomObjectA) o);
        if(o instanceof CustomObjectB) myMethod((CustomObjectB) o);
    }
    public static void myMethod(CustomObjectA a) { }
    public static void myMethod(CustomObjectB b) { }
}

interface CustomObject {}
class CustomObjectA implements CustomObject {}
class CustomObjectB implements CustomObject {}
```